# Ionic Lag Between Transtions

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm working on an `Ionic v1` tabbed application with a few images and lists displayed.

When I'm testing the app on any Android Device, I experience a 1-5 second lag between selecting the device's back button and when the transition takes place.

This happens when I navigate to a new page within a tab, scroll down, then select the back button.

- The back button on the app itself works just fine with no lag
- If I navigate to the new page and **don't** scroll, the device back button works fine
- I'm not displaying a lot of data at one time. This lag occurs even with a single image displayed

I've had this issue for quite some time, there's several Github tickets on this but none of them have a solution. Anyone have any ideas whatsoever on how to resolve this?

Comment: Better to add your working code snippet to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that enabling JS Scrolling where I have a fair amount of content fixes my issue. By default I leave it disabled on Android, and utilize `overflow-scroll="true"` on views where it's needed.

Note this issue does not occur when using `collection-repeat`